# Show block only in user own page and for administrator role users

Tags: 7, blocks, users

What I'm trying to achieve:

1. User can see block only on his own "user/[uid]/my-page" - he cant see that block on other users my-page.
2. Users who belong to administrator role can see user block on user own page.

Right now my code shows block for user himself and also to administrator role users BUT for administrator role users it shows block on every page - not only in "my-page".

How to modify code to show block only in "my-page" also for administrator role users?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
global $user;
if (in_array('administrator', ($user->roles))) {
return TRUE;
}
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1) && arg(2) == "my-page" ) {
return TRUE;
}   
else {
return FALSE;
}
?>
```

I used this code as a base: https://drupal.org/node/134433

Comment: In my experience Block visibility with PHP script does not work as expected always. Try to create block in your module with hook_block_info() and hook_block_view() and put your logic into content generation part of hook_block_view()

Comment: why you are adding if (in_array('administrator', ($user->roles))) {
return TRUE;
} ?

Comment: What kind of block is it. This is important because there may be better ways to hid & show the block. For example a views block can achieve this through use of filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost a replica of your code with a small change. I hope it helps.

1. If you want to allow the admin to see the block on every other user profile page

   ```
   global $user;
   if (arg(0) == 'user' && ($user->uid == arg(1) || in_array('administrator', ($user->roles))) && arg(2) == "my-isn10") {
     return TRUE;
   }
   else {
     return FALSE;
   }
   ```
2. If admin or normal user do not have a difference both can see only on their profile page.

   ```
   global $user;
   if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1) && arg(2) == "my-page" ) {
     return TRUE;
   }   
   else {
     return FALSE;
   }
   ```

Comment: I am not sure why code is not picking up the code style